# Gmail "Message left on the server", how to automatically delete them?

Tags: gmail, virus, spam-prevention

In the last few weeks, I've been receiving many alerts from Gmail while reading emails from another account. The warnings, for example, read `Message left on the server: "Thank you for setting the order No. 475456"`, because they contain some virus or dangerous attachment (spam, naturally).

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell Gmail to automatically delete those message **on the original server** (I don't want to remove the warning message "Message left on the server", but the original dangerous message).

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87036/117263

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not from inside gmail, you'd have to connect to the other account directly.  If the other accounts provide a webmail service that would be the simplest way.

Comment: Yes, and this if what im doing actually, but im ondering if there was to tell gmail to do that.

Well, no chance to do it.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately not, I hope this gets added in the future. You can, however, prevent the warning messages:

Create a filter in Gmail.

Go to *Settings > Filters > Create a new filter*.

In the subject field, type "**`Message left on server:`**", then click **Next**.

Select the "**Delete It**" option and click **Create Filter**.

**NOTE:**
This will auto delete the message in Gmail, however, the messages are still left on the server, so you'll have to log in to the account directly every now and then to clear out the messages. It's still a lot less annoying IMO.

Comment: I dont delete anything from gmail ;)
Actually i have a filter that ignore the inbox folder for those message and give them a label..

Well, maybe when the 'delete on server' function will be avaiable, i will delete it from gmail too ;)

Comment: I believe in June 2015 Google dropped the "Message left on server:" subject prefix so these items started to reappear in my inbox. I'm now using "from:(mail-noreply@google.com) contained a virus or a suspicious attachment."

Comment: There's an updated instruction here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87041/117263